# User can Edit/Delete only their own post ASP.NET CORE 5.0 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Sorry for asking maybe a stupid question but I have no idea what and where to look about some guide or solution. I am working on my own application where users can only see and delete their own post.
For example, If I have 5 user registered in the system, every user can only see posts which `he/she'll create.
Sorry for not provide my source code, but I have no idea what do I need to provide. If you need some specific part please let me know and I will post.
Cheers!

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VmSTicketing.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using VmSTicketing.Models;
using VmSTicketing.Models.ViewModels;
using VmSTicketing.Utility;

namespace Ticketing.Areas.Manager.Controllers
{
    [Area("Manager")]
    [Authorize(Roles = SD.Role_Admin + "," + SD.Role_Manager)]
    public class TicketController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfwork;
        public TicketController(IUnitOfWork unitOfwork)
        {
            _unitOfwork = unitOfwork;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Upsert(int? Id)
        {

            TicketVM ticketVM = new TicketVM()
            {
                Ticket = new Ticket(),
                TicketTypeList = _unitOfwork.TicketType.GetAll().Select(i => new SelectListItem
                {
                    Text = i.Name,
                    Value = i.Id.ToString()
                })
            };

            if (Id == null)
            {
                return View(ticketVM);
            }

            ticketVM.Ticket = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id.GetValueOrDefault());

            if (ticketVM.Ticket == null)
            {
                NotFound();
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upsert(TicketVM ticketVM)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (ticketVM.Ticket.Id == 0)
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Add(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                else
                {
                    _unitOfwork.Ticket.Update(ticketVM.Ticket);
                }
                _unitOfwork.Save();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(ticketVM);
        }




        #region API CALLS
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetAll()
        {
            var obj = _unitOfwork.Ticket.GetAll(includeProperties: "TicketType");
            return Json(new { data = obj });
        }


        [HttpDelete]
        public IActionResult Delete(int Id)
        {
            
            var objFromDb = _unitOfwork.Ticket.Get(Id);
            if (objFromDb == null)
            {
                return Json(new { success = false, message = "Error while deleting" });
            }
            _unitOfwork.Ticket.Remove(objFromDb);
            _unitOfwork.Save();
            return Json(new { success = true, message = "Delete Successfull" });
        }

        #endregion

    }
}
```

Comment: One thing you can do is just grab the data based on the userId? That way you grab all posts just for a specific user.
Example: _unitOfwork.Posts.Where(x => x.UserId == userid);

Comment: What do I need to do in my view ?

Comment: You didnt post your view on here, however, your view should continue as is. So for example, if your view just has a table a it loops through all the posts, it can stay that way because what matters is that your are returning only the posts related to that user in your controller.

Comment: @Filipe Nice, thank you !